# Vertical align of text in CSS

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align a Fontawsome Icon (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) with some text next to it. In this case a phone number next to a - you guessed it - phone icon.

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <i class="fa fa-3x fa-phone-square"></i>
    <span class="phone">111 222 333</span>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.phone {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ypLN5/

I tried several things playing around with line-height and vertical-align: middle but I haven't come up with a solution.

May you help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very very easy way of doing this:

```
i, span{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

## [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/ypLN5/2/)

Comment: Nice and easy, +1. Although, what is worth mentioning is that if the span's content is beyond its computed width it will break into new line and go beneath the phone icon. To prevent that you can set a fixed width for the `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

SW4's answer is correct.

Although if you are looking to center inside of a bigger element using `display: table-cell` and will solve your problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/3U2Vj/1/